# Bluetooth LE Mouse keeps freezing in after a while

Tags: windows-7, mouse, bluetooth

My mouse keeps freezing after an hour or so of not using it. Tried a lot of tweaks like disabling Selective Suspend in registry keys but to no avail. Everything goes back to normal and connects when I restart or wake up the PC. Tried other bluetooth mice and it does the same.

Using a Qualcomm QCA6174A USB integrated Bluetooth module. Windows 7 with 4.0.0.791 driver.

Comment: Have you tried Power Settings in the Bluetooth driver?  Have you updated the driver?

Comment: Yes, still nothing.

Comment: A possible hardware error with the card, or maybe incompatible with the very old OS.